SSIS Looping through Databases via ODBC
I am trying to connect to different databases via an ODBC connection using a ForEach Loop Container in SSIS. The database list is coming from a Extract SQL Task.
I have set up an expression for the ODBC connection to use ConnectionString with the following Expression:
"Dsn=xxxx;uid=yyyy;Database=" + @[User::dbName] + ";"
Unfortunately when I run the package I get a connection issue. I tried replacing @[User::dbName] with an actual database name and it works. But it just iterates over the same database.
When using the above Expression I noticed the Connection String in the Properties Section of the Connection, the database is blank as per below. This makes sense since @[User::dbName] hasnt been populated but not sure how to get around this.
ConnectionString: Dsn=xxxx;uid=yyyy;Database=;
Was seeing if anyone can please assist?

I wonder if it would work if you set the DelayValidation property to True for this connection. If DelayValidation is false, SSIS will try to validate all connections at the beginning of the run. That said, I'm not even sure what you're trying to do is possible (I could be wrong).

Did you declare the [User::dbName] as object and in for each loop did you selected the Foreach ADO Enumerator option to iterate over the databases stored in object.?

Thanks Jake I tired this but no luck.

SQL006 yep I did declare has an object. The for each loop works when I pass a SQL Command to it. It just has issues when looping through databases using the connection string. Not sure if this can be done via ODBC?

With questions about SSIS, it often helps to show screenshots of your package layouts, details, and dataflows. It sounds like you @[User::dbName] variable isn't getting populated, but it's really hard to be sure without seeing what's actually going on with all the various moving parts and metadata of the package.
